# How to hide "index.php?go=" from my URL?

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I’m interested to know, find a solution, how can I hide "index.php?go=" from my URL.

Actually my url is displayed like this: http://mywebsite.com/index.php?go=home
I have been looking for a good solution but I didn't find a good one :( I tryed with htacces and best that I found was to hide only "index.php" not all that I needed. Now with htaccess enabled my link is displayed like this: http://mywebsite.com/?go=home ....

Can anyone find I good solution how to hide that "?go=" from the URL?

I will really appreciate your answer.

Comment: You want something like an `.htaccess` router?

Comment: do u want its to be like `http://mywebsite.com/home` ? this is same as your old url but cleaner

Comment: yes if its posible...

Answer (score 1):

You can use URL Rewriting. It's server-side.
You define rules and patterns. In `.htaccess` file.

It looks like this: `RewriteRule /([a-z]+)/ /index.php?go=$1`
This would rewrite `/home/` into `/index.php?go=home`

You can do very powerful things with it.

But you'll need to define the "format" of your URL.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work!! :( Thank you however